# The glue function needs to refer to the data frame by a dollar sign in geom_brackets

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr, r-glue

I have a code like this

```
#creating a categorical variable from a continuous one.
lobxx <- Loblolly %>% 
           mutate(ageG = if_else(age < 10,"A", if_else(age == 10, "B", if_else(age > 10, "C", "NA"))))
```

```
#calculating the t value
dfxx <- lobxx %>%
          rstatix::df_arrange(ageG,age) %>%
          rstatix::t_test(height~ageG) %>%
          rstatix::add_xy_position(x="ageG")
```

```
#creating a plot using ggplot and ggpubr::geom_bracket
dfxplotx <- ggplot(lobxx,aes(x= reorder(ageG,-height),y=height,fill=ageG))+
        stat_summary(geom="col",fun = mean)+
        ggpubr::geom_bracket(mapping=aes(xmin = group1, xmax = group2),data = dfxx,
                label = glue("P:{dfxx$p.adj}{dfxx$p.adj.signif}"),
                        y.position = c(53,60,53),
                        bracket.nudge.y = 5,inherit.aes = F)

dfxplotx
```

You can notice that I used the dollar sign to refer to the data frame.
The point is that I noticed that most examples on the web did not use a format like this (data frame $ variable). Is there something wrong with the code or has something changed elsewhere?
thank you.

I tried this code without using the $ sing in the glue function but I had error message. Why should this happen.

Comment: not the thing you're asking about, but `if_else(age < 10,"A", if_else(age == 10, "B", if_else(age > 10, "C", "NA"))))` is equivalent to `case_when(age < 10 ~ "A", age == 10 ~ "B", age > 10 ~"C")`, but the second one is shorter and easier to read (also don't do `"NA"`, it's `NA`, it shouldn't be a string

Comment: it's hard to tell what's going on since you didn't give us a reproducible example (dput is your friend), but I'm guessing either a. it can be done, but you just didn't do it, or b. the fact that you're introducing a second dataframe for the geom_bracket part, perhaps in the case of two different dataframes it needs to be specified

Comment: Could you clarify what's the issue? Do you get an error message or ....? In general using `$` to refer to dataset columns should work. Also, dropping `dfxx$` should work as well if you move `label=` inside `aes()`. Finally, please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data best shared via `dput()`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I appreciate your advice. Dropping dfxx$ did not work. Inside aes(), I had to use glue(). However, several examples did not and use a formula like this:  label = "pvalue {p.adj}" for the database I use data(Loblolly) for exercise. That is my inquiry about when to use glue() and when it is feasible to use "{}" without glue(). I do appreciate your experience and patience.

Comment: dput(dfxplotx) @Mark

Comment: @hanysalem try running that, and then edit your question and add the results in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an alternative to $ syntax for pulling things out of lists is square brackets.
When they both work there is no benefit to using one or the other apart from style/habit. However square bracket syntax is more general / powerful, as it can be used directly for metaprogramming; i.e. writing code which relies on the contents of variables to do one thing or another. Here is an example

```
myl <- list(x=1,y="a")

# direct access is just as good for one as another
# lets say we want the x contents from myl which is `1`
myl$x
myl["x"]
# but the square bracket took me 3 more keypresses to write

#if we want to write code with an additional level of `indirection`
# i.e. we didnt write code to get either x or y from myl
# we write code to get whatever of x or y another variable `get_me_` says to get 
get_me_<- "y"

# we can do this with square brackets
myl[get_me_]
# $y
# [1] "a"

# this is simply not a thing with $ syntax ; you would need to get into 
# parseing and evaluating string commands to force such an approach to work
myl$get_me_
# hence why square brackets are more 'powerful'
```